# R - how to reload function (or change package priority)

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, r-s4, bioconductor

I am using the Matrix library to work with sparse matrices. Occasionally, I need to run a function that uses a Bioconductor package, which depends on the S4Vectors library. Unfortunately, the "colSums" function in Matrix conflicts with the "colSums" function in S4Vectors. Therefore, when I run this function, it breaks my "colSums" function, which is really annoying.

I know that there are two common solutions to this problem:
1) Load the Bioconductor package *before* loading the Matrix library - however, I seldom use this function, so I would prefer to only load the Bioconductor package when I need it.
2) Instead of calling "colSums", call "Matrix::colSums" - however, this is super inconvenient and I would need to change my entire code base.

Ideally, I would just load the Bioconductor package, run my function, then cleanup my environment by either unloading the Bioconductor package or reloading the Matrix package. However, I am having trouble doing these. First, is it possible to reload the Matrix::colSums (so that it replaces S4Vectors::colSums)? Second, when I try to unload S4Vectors, R complains because many other packages depend on it.

So aside from the obvious question of why S4Vectors has a function that conflicts with the most used sparse matrix package in R, I'm wondering what the best solution to this problem is? It can't possibly be that difficult to simply reload a package, right?

Comment: Update: The best solution was recommended by Kota Mori, using the "unloadNamespace" function to first unload the Matrix package before reloading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is, as you already know, to write `Matrix::colSums`.

A simple solution, which does not require rewriting your code would be to add a line

```
colSums <- Matrix::colSums
```

somewhere in your code.  Then this `colSums` belongs to your global environment, hence is found before any other libraries.

## EDIT

I found a better solution.
I will demonstrate with `plyr` and `dplyr` since they both have `arrange` function and cause a conflict.

Example1. `dplyr` loaded later, hence wins.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
environment(arrange)  
# <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

Example 2.  `plyr` wins

```
# unload libraries
unloadNamespace("plyr")
unloadNamespace("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
environment(arrange)
```

The key is the search order, which you can find by `search` function.
Below, you can see `plyr` comes before `dplyr`.

```
search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:plyr"      "package:dplyr"     "tools:rstudio"    
# [5] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
# [9] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Example 3. You can specify where in search list you want to load a library; `pos` argument.

```
unloadNamespace("plyr")
unloadNamespace("dplyr")    

library(plyr)
library(dplyr, pos=length(search()))
environment(arrange)
# <environment: namespace:plyr>

search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:plyr"      "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
# [5] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
# [9] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:dplyr"     "package:base"
```

In conclusion, you can load `Bioconductor` library with giving a large number as `pos`.
That said, you said `Bioconductor` depends on `S4Vector` and `S4Vector` is the one causing conflict.  Unfortunately you cannot control the position for depended packages directly since `require` statement is within the `Bioconductor` package.
A workaround is that you load `S4Vector` first with `pos` option, then load `Bioconductor`:

```
library(S4Vector, pos=10)  # replace 10 by an appropriate large number
library(Bioconductor)
```

Then, `S4Vector` will be placed after `Matrix` in the search order.

## YET ANOTHER SOLUTION

If you want to reload `Matrix`, then you can also do like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
environment(arrange)
# <environment: namespace:plyr>

unloadNamespace("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
environment(arrange)
# <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the perfect solution and I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
library(lubridate)
```

lubdridate overides date. A message pops up that says: The following object is masked from ‘package:base’: date
But you can still get to the original date function.

```
base::date()
```

So you don't have look at load order. Just be specific in which function you use.